# Why do we have Top N Sort in this example?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan

In the example below the result of `Index Spool` is already sorted, why do we have `Top N Sort` here instead of simple `Top`?

```
use tempdb;
go

create table dbo.t1 (id int identity primary key, v int);
create table dbo.t2 (id int identity primary key, v int);

insert into dbo.t1
(v)
select top (1000)
row_number() over (order by 1/0)
from
master.dbo.spt_values a cross join
master.dbo.spt_values b;

insert into dbo.t2
(v)
select top (10000)
row_number() over (order by 1/0) + 10000
from
master.dbo.spt_values a cross join
master.dbo.spt_values b;

set statistics xml, io on;

select
sum(a.v + b.v)
from
dbo.t1 a outer apply
(select top (1) v from dbo.t2 where v >= a.v order by v) b;

set statistics xml,io off;
go

drop table dbo.t1, dbo.t2;
go
```

[image]

It's reproducible in all versions starting from `2008 R2` (I just have no server with earlier versions to test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a somewhat annoying limitation of the current optimizer.

I wrote about this a little as part of [The Eager Index Spool and The Optimizer](https://sqlperformance.com/2019/11/sql-performance/eager-index-spool-optimizer):

> Index spools do not tell the optimizer they support output ordered by the spool's index keys. If sorted output from the spool is required, you may see an unnecessary Sort operator. Eager index spools should often be replaced by a permanent index anyway, so this is a minor concern much of the time.

Answer (score -1):

Because you order by `[v]`, while your primary key is on `[id]`.

BTW: the query could become slightly faster, when you use `SUM(a.v) + ISNULL(SUM(b.v), NULL)` instead of `sum(a.v + b.v)`.

On the other hand the result could vary a little bit in this case, since you use OUTER APPLY (similar to a LEFT JOIN), so when there is no record found for the "table" `[b]`, it would ignore the `a.v` in the original query too (since `a.v + NULL` is `NULL`) while `a.v` it would be in the total sum of my suggested version (it's your data, so you have to decide, if you remain on the `sum(a.v + b.v)` it would be a good target for a comment saying, that this is the intended behavior :-).